# How to replace useEffect with componentDidMount if we call a callback function inside componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle, react-lifecycle-hooks

by using useEffect, my array state variable did not append the previous value, but componentDidMount did

I console.log out the message when using the useEffect, and all the message were correctedly printed out, but the state wasn't stored, if I set the messages state variable as the dependency of the useEffect, it goes into an infinite loop

```
// with useEffect hook
function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const chatManager = new ChatManager({
      instanceLocator: instanceLocator,
      userId: 'Henry',
      tokenProvider: new TokenProvider({
        url: tokenUrl
      })
    });

    chatManager.connect()
      .then(currentUser => {
        currentUser.subscribeToRoomMultipart({
          roomId: '7b7a1d23-e869-4c19-8eab-e88d5144dd72',
          hooks: {
            onMessage: message => {
             console.log([...messages]);
              setMessages([...messages, message]);
            }
          }
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error on connection', err)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <RoomList />
      <MessageList messages={messages}/>
      <SendMessageForm />
      <NewRoomForm />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

// with componentDidMount
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      messages: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const chatManager = new ChatManager({
      instanceLocator,
      userId: 'Henry',
      tokenProvider: new TokenProvider({
        url: tokenUrl
      })
    })

    chatManager.connect()
      .then(currentUser => {
        currentUser.subscribeToRoomMultipart({
          roomId: '7b7a1d23-e869-4c19-8eab-e88d5144dd72',
          hooks: {
            onMessage: message => {
              this.setState({
                messages: [...this.state.messages, message]
              })
            }
          }
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <RoomList />
        <MessageList messages={this.state.messages} />
        <SendMessageForm />
        <NewRoomForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

I expect the result of using useEffect the same as componentDidMount which hash all the message inside the messages state array variable, yet by using useEffect, I can console out all the message, but the messages state array variable is empty so the final result is only the latest message.

Comment: It looks like your component is resetting state between renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your state depends on the current state value, you need to use the functional form of `setMessages`. This means you don't need to include `messages` as a dependency (because it actually won't be a dependency):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ...

    chatManager.connect()
      .then(currentUser => {
        currentUser.subscribeToRoomMultipart({
          roomId: '7b7a1d23-e869-4c19-8eab-e88d5144dd72',
          hooks: {
            onMessage: message => {
              setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, message]);
            }
          }
        })
      })
  }, [])
```

See the React docs for more info:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates